# Finding data at given location info with SQL query

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a table structure like the following

```
idx   p_id    location_id  

1     CTX      A1
2     CTX      A2
3     ABC      A3
4     ABC      A1
```

idx is auto increment number and indicating the latest location
(for product CTX case, it transfered from A1 to A2)

NOW, what I want to find is any product in location A1.
I should find only product ABC, since product CTX moved from A1 to A2, it no longer in the A1

Is there easy way to perform with SQL query?

Comment: in your table ctx , A1 is saved or it gets deleted after changing from A1 to A2

Comment: By right there has to be an update...

Comment: if update would be there then he'll get only desired result..but this is not the case he is inserting rows without any updation to previous one..

Comment: Previous data is there, that's why he hasn't deleted `CTX A1`. And entering a new reocrd `ABC A1` it seems `max(idx)` fits best.according to the sameple data.

Comment: no update, because I need to know products's transfer history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to find all rows where the max dx for a given p_id has a location of 'A1'

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   table1 t 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT p_id, 
                          Max(dx) dx 
                   FROM   table1 
                   GROUP  BY p_id) max_dx 
               ON t.dx = max_dx.dx 
WHERE  t.location_id = 'A1'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50565/6)

If you don't like sub queries for some reason you can do an ANTI-JOIN on an inequality on the PK

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   table1 t 
       LEFT JOIN table1 t2
       ON t.p_id = t2.p_id 
          and t.dx < t2.dx
WHERE
     t2.dx IS NULL
     and t.location_id = 'A1'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50565/11)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after re-reading your question, I think this is more what you need:

```
SELECT idx, p_id, location_id
FROM tablename t0 JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(idx) AS m
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY p_id) t1
  ON t0.idx = t1.m
WHERE t0.location_id = 'A1';
```

Comment: After re-reading the question, I think this is not what the OP is looking for. I'm working on a refinement...

Comment: And to be fair, you should probably award Conrad Frix the answer since he read your question correctly and came up with the query before I did.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The dumbest way:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PRODUCT_ID
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE
 LOCATION_ID = "A1" -- of course use parameter in real application!
ORDER BY
 ID DESC
```

HOWEVER! This is incorrect because one can not safely rely on sequencing of IDS,(even if it works in 99% of cases). Why don't you add a timestamp column?

You can also use a MAX() function to get a subquery returning max ID:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_ID
 FROM YOUR_TABLE
 WHERE
 LOCATION_ID = "A1" -- of course use parameter in real application!
AND
 ID = SLECT MAX(ID) FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE LOCATION_ID = "A1"
```

Comment: If you have four spaces before each line you post will be nicely formatted. If you select your code and press the `{}` button it will format your code. Also TOP 1 won't work in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get the latest location without using a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT p_id, location_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY idx DESC) RowNumber
) x
WHERE RowNumber = 1 AND location_id = 'A1'
```

Comment: Unfortunately mySQL doesn't support Row_Number(). Although you could do it [with this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1895127/119477) but its hard to get the (PARTITION BY to work)

Comment: if more than one product id have same location id then also it will give only the latest result.

Comment: @ConradFrix oops, I missed the mysql tag. I'll leave the answer as it may be useful for others.

Comment: @sourcecode I disagree. The Partition By clause will reset the row counter for each unique p_id. Each unique p_id will have a record with RowNumber = 1. If that row also hapopens to lave a location_id of  "A1" then it will be returned in the result set.

Comment: as an aside you can still write this without a subquery or row_number [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/50565/11)

Comment: @ConradFrix Nice, I like this solution.